# A sufficient condition for positive determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant

The following problems is from the book Berkeley Problems in the Mathematics. The solution is not given for this problem.

**Problem**:Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix with diagonal entries non-negative and all other entries non-positive. Also any column sum is strictly positive.

Show  $det(A)>0$

I am only able to see this for $2 \times 2 $ case. Since $a_{11} > -a_{21}$ and $a_{22} > -a_{12}$ from the positive column sum conditions.

Now we can multiply the inequalities since both sides are positive, to get $a_{11}a_{22} > a_{21}a_{12}$.

But this idea doesn't generalize when we go to higher dimensions since we get many other terms than 'product over permutations'.

I tried writing this as: $A^{t}(1, 1, 1)^t > 0 , e_iAe_j \leq 0$ and $e_iAe_i \geq 0$ but this also doesn't seem to lead anywhere. This matrix need not be positive definite as the given conditions don't extend to submatrices.

Am I missing some property of Linear Transformations with positive determinant?

In the $2 \times 2$ case, I see the following geometrical interpretation:  $A$ has positive determinant IFF the angle between first row and second row (going anticlockwise starting from the  first row) is less than $180^{\circ}$ but I couldn't generalize this to higher dimensions either.

I am looking for hints. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we show that
$$\langle Ax,x\rangle >0,\qquad x\neq 0\qquad\ \ (*)$$
$$\displaylines{\langle Ax,x\rangle=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}x_i^2 +\sum_{i\neq j}a_{ij}x_ix_j \\ \ge \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}x_i^2-\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|\,|x_i|\,|x_j|}$$
Next
$$\displaylines{\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|\,|x_i|\,|x_j|\le {1\over 2} \left (\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|\,x_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|\,x_j^2\right )\\
=\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|\,x_i^2\le \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n|a_{ij}|<
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}x_i^2}$$
This implies $(*),$
which in turn gives  that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive. Therefore $\det A>0.$

**Remark** The proof can be slightly modified to capture the case of complex space $\mathbb{C}^n$ and a self-adjoint matrix $A$ such that
$$\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^n|a_{ij}|<a_{ii}$$